# Giving script timeout passed on database import

Tags: mysql, magento, wamp, wampserver

I am using wamp server.I am trying to import the database in phpmyadmin. but its showing

Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.

And if i check the database tables only few tables are imported..How to resolve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: what is size of your database file which your are importing.?

Comment: database size is 64 MB

Comment: i think default size is  3MB allowed. You are importing it on localhost or server.. :)

Comment: yes i am running in localhost..And i have changed file maximum upload size in php.ini like upload_max_filesize = 750M..

Comment: No its php file uploading size..not phpmyadmin follow blow given link steps and it will be done..

Comment: if you found my answer help ful.. please vote up and make it verified.. :)

Answer (score 15):

Add following code

`$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

in your phpmyadmin config.inc.php and it will solve your timeout problem, this should work on both XAMPP and WAMP

Comment: This is not working on MAC. I change from 300 to 0  and restart the xampp but it still showing 300

Answer (score 6):

Its quite common when importing a database of any size using phpMyAdmin, to blow the max_execution limit that comes with most php installations.

If you want to increase the maximum time allocated to phpMyAdmin rather than to your whole Apache/PHP environment:

In the alias file `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`, just before , you can add

Assuming you have Apache 2.4.x

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
    # Increase runtime 
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Or is you have Apache 2.2.x

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
    # Increase runtime 
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Of course you could just use the `MySQL Console` as the console has no limits placed on it by PHP. This command used at the MySQL Console prompt `mysql>` will load the database dump file and do the restore.

```
source c:\path\to\your\database\dump\file.sql
```

**Update**

For some time now WAMPServer comes with these parameters set in the `\wamp{64}\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file, however, occasionally even with the new defaults you may need to increase them for a very large import

Answer (score 0):

For xampp : In xampp Folder go phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and set $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
same process in wampp

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to follow these steps so that you can upload large size database files..[click here for more assistance](http://programmingpoint.wordpress.com/category/phpmyadmin/)

Comment: I followed the procedure given in that link but its showing same error

Comment: Yes...do it like this in php.ini
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = 0