# set foreign_key_checks = on error wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have Bluehost account and now i am transferring to new account digitalocean.com i am doing export and import as we do in the phpmyadmin but here when i import my sql.zip or sql.gz files in new server it show me error like

```
Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation

#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

Here is the screen shot

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2511553/fa78fad9e1108051c84538f2314df7

**i do following steps to resolve issue**

1. try to export by MYSQL_40 and import
2. try by disabling the FOREIGN_KEY checkbox when export and try to import
3. Used the database plugin but same error

But no luck i think it is an issue with bluehost server when i am trying to export

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974492/error-while-importing-wp-options-table-for-wordpress-a-foreign-key-error see if it helps.

Comment: @CesarMartinezDominguez thanks for the reply but I check this options as well not luck and at the end, I change the server and migrate to HostGator and also the support of Bluehost is worst. I am not saying I am right but they should have technical support like HostGator & wpengine.

Answer (score 17):

After checking lots of solutions finally i found the correct one, my wordpress database size was 100mb.

```
Changing php.ini at C:\xampp\php\php.ini
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
user_ini.cache_ttl = 15000
```

```
Changing my.ini at C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini</b>
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
```

Comment: Hi Vinit, So so you know why you need to add max limit for digital ocen server?

Comment: thank this parameters I changed and could import sql

Comment: Thanks mate! As a note for Mamp users: to edit the max_allowed_packet, go to PhpMyAdmin -> Variables and set it to 1073741824 (which is equal to 1024M).

Answer (score 5):

This Error, Mostly We get while importing the database from PhpMyAdmin. I solved it by importing database through commands.

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file_name.sql
```

or by changing in database `file_name.sql` as:

1. put this line `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` just the beginning of database `file_name.sql`.
2. And put this line `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` just before the end of file at last line of `file_name.sql`.

**Note:** The first line will disable foreign key checks and the last line will enable it again.

[How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

once it happened to me
It's because you've been using MariaDB 10.3 and now you changed the version to lower
take a backup
change or update/upgrade the version of your mariadb or mysql to the latest and then it will be ok

Comment: I have MariaDB version 15.1 and I'm still getting that error.