# Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file and import will resume

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin, ini

I have a database
Un-zipped size `50mb` zipped size `7mb` 
So when I try to import the database **zipped**(7mb) after few minutes it is throwing this error:

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please **resubmit**
>   the same file and import will resume.

I have resubmitted it but still not importing total data.

I am working in local and these are my php.ini configurations:

```
max_execution_time = 3000000 
max_input_time = 60000000000000
memory_limit = 1280000000000000000000M
post_max_size = 4096456M
upload_max_filesize = 40964564M
max_file_uploads = 200
```

how can I let the system to take its own time for import.?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you are importing your database using Phpmyadmin, then there's a configuration file for it. The default/example config file is found here:

```
\phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php
```

Don't edit this file as it may get overwritten in future updates. Instead look for an existing file here:

```
\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php
```

...and if it does not exist, create it.

Open this configuration file in any editor and change `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

(or if it does not exist, add it)

Restart your localhost, now you don't have any time limit.

Or you can use MySQL command line to import your unzipped SQL file directly, something like below:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < my_unzipped_import_file.sql
```

Comment: What do you mean by restarting localhost ? apache server ? or mysql server ? thanks

Comment: If you are going to change Phpmyadmin config, then you don't have to restart anything. @MindRoasterMir

Comment: I am using AWS server, where I can get the config.default.php fiel?

Comment: Thank you, i use Open Server Panel, my path: C:\OpenServer\modules\system\html\openserver\phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php

Answer (score 16):

Go to xampp/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php 
find `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` line no 695 and replace `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

Answer (score 11):

Instead of XAMPP you may use LAMP(Linux Apache MySQL PHP) mostly. Using LAMP you may also face this problem.

In my case(using Ubuntu 15.10), I had configured/set post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit following my needs using php.ini file which is located at **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

But still I was faced this problem. Then solved the problem using  config.default.php file, where you can find out like this line below:

**$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;**
Make it to

**$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;**

**Note**: You can locate config.default.php file via your terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) by this commandlocate config.default.php possible path is /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php

Answer (score 8):

You need to change

```php
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
```

to

```php
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

in your `config.php` file located by default in `\phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php`

Restart your localhost.

It will definitely work. Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

Xampp in Ubuntu

If you are importing your database using `PhpMyAdmin`, then there's a configuration file for it:

> /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php

Open this configuration file in any editor and change `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300`; to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0`;

Restart your `localhost`, now you don't have any time limit.

Answer (score 4):

## WampServer Version 3 - Windows

Open **config.default.php**

You can find it here

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php
```

Search for **ExecTimeLimit**

```
/**
 * maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
 *
 * @global integer $cfg['ExecTimeLimit']
 */
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
```

increase the value of **$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']** or set it to **0** for no limit

Answer (score 3):

in

```
config.inc.php
```

add this

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

for me is work

Answer (score 2):

**MAC OS MAMP**

edit this file

```
/Applications/MAMP/./bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

and dont forget restart MAMP

Answer (score 1):

for lamp ubuntu :-
first go to  config.default.php location you can find by execute

```
locate config.default.php
```

in my case its locate at /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries

```
cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries
```

now edit config.default.php file in my case i use gedit you can install by

```
sudo apt install gedit

sudo gedit config.default.php
```

no search for ExecTimeLimit in file change $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300; to

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

save  and close it, restart server by

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

This way will work with **Windows OS + WAMP server**

---

You can directly import **.sql** file via MySQL server by calling it from your CMD at this path `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\bin`

1- Open your CMD
2- `cd C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\bin`
3- `mysql -u root -p < {/path/to/your/sql/file/.sql}`

This way didn't have a limitation on execution time compared to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are importing your database using Phpmyadmin, then there's a configuration file for it: \phpmyadmin\libraries\config.default.php

The way it is described in the accepted answer by @Tejashwi Kalp Taru has it's flaws.

@Gibran Dimasagung mentioned the correct way, by editing

> config.inc.php

as the header of the config.default.php file cleary states following:

> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT config.inc.php INSTEAD !!!
> phpMyAdmin default configuration, you can copy values from here to
> your config.inc.php

It's likely that all changes applied to config.default.php will be lost after an update.

Comment: If you feel one answer is better than another you should upvote the one that helped you. When you [have enough rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you will also be able to comment and downvote accordingly. In the mean time, you can suggest an edit to the helpful answer which adds the extra details you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a docker image like 
[phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin) for instance, you can achieve do this:

1. Bash into your docker image: docker exec -it the-name-of-your-image bash
2. cd /etc/phpmyadmin, then you will see a file name **config.inc.php**
3. open the file with **nano** or **vim** (You will have to install them in the container if you haven't)
4. Scroll down and check, you'll see this line: `if (isset($_ENV['MAX_EXECUTION_TIME'])) { $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = $_ENV['EXEC_TIME_LIMIT']; }`
5. change `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = $_ENV['EXEC_TIME_LIMIT'];` to `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;` as suggested above.
6. Save, exit and restart your image. You should be fine