# Left join Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)

Tags: mysql, sql

when i try the following

```
SELECT serials.device_id
FROM serials
LEFT JOIN performance
ON serials.device_id = performance.device_id
```

i get

> (Error Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25) SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error (near "ON" at position 25) while importing Table for WORDPRESS ( A foreign key Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974492/error-near-on-at-position-25-while-importing-table-for-wordpress-a-foreign)

Answer (score 0):

This error message is rather confusing, but here's what it actually can mean:

- Server side timeout without automatic reconnection set up.
- Server has dropped a connection while you are using Windows client.
- Client-side timeout.
- Logic error in application.
- You (or server admin) has killed a running thread with a command like mysqladmin kill.

Since I do not see the context (other than left join) of the error here, it would be nice if you posted more details:

- Is this error happening when you are using mysql client, or, while you are trying to access MySQL programmatically?
- Please state the operating system.
- If you are accessing MySQL programmatically, is there any back trace?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your_file_name.sql and Search this line

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`
```

Change from this

```
MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=33195;
```

to this

```
MODIFY `ID` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=33195;
```