# script timeout Xampp v3.2.2 - database import

Tags: database, xampp, timeout

I've recently upgraded my Xampp environment to v3.2.2 of the software.  I have the same versions running on 2 different machines using the same configuration for both environments.

By the same configuration, I mean that I got the software working the way I wanted on one machine, shut down Xampp, zipped up the folder, and copied that folder over to the other machine where it started right up.  I do not use the Xampp installer, I download the full zip file.

Here is a list revised configuration files for both machines:
paths are relative to Xampp folder.

- apache/conf/httpd.conf
- apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
- php/php.ini
- php/pear.bat
- php/pciconf.bat
- php/bin/my.ini
- phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
- setup_xampp.bat

The issue I'm having is that the same database that imports through the same version of phpMyAdmin works on one machine and not the other.

To no avail, I tried adding this line of code to the phpMyAdmin config file.
    `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

That was recommended in this thread:
[Giving script timeout passed on database import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140679/giving-script-timeout-passed-on-database-import)

I'm running 2 versions of Xampp.  That is all working fine.  Interestingly, the same database will import on the offending machine without timing out on Xampp v3.2.1.  I use the same configurations for that version of Xampp too.

Could this have something to do with MariaDB?  The older version of Xampp used mySQL.

I can work around the issue, for now, but I'd sure appreciate solving the mystery of why I can import on one machine and not the other.

Thanks, in advance, for any helpful replies.

Comment: You folks can disregard this question.  I got it working by meticulously creating a folder with all configuration changes and copying those back into the offending machine's installation of Xampp.  All is now well with the world.

Comment: In other words, the problem is solved.